# Style gone wrong in product page

Tags: template, css, product-page

I was updating some content the other day in my site http://www.kabayandundee.co.uk/tindahan when suddenly the product pages lost their styling.

I was not meddling with the templates or code at all, only updating content and uploading images.

After that happened I tried installing and activating new themes but the product pages remain the same no matter what I do.

I am not sure where this can be easily fixed or if it would be better to start a new installation from scratch? Also, I would like to know what has gone wrong, so I can, at least, learn from this.

Thanks a lot for your time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see that your theme name is 'defalt/f001', but on the product pages the styles from the `base/default` theme are loaded.
Since you say you were only changing content I would say that you changed the theme for a certain products and/or categories.
retrace your steps, and edit some product or category you already edited and look at the `Design` tab for products or `Custom  Design` tab for categories. Make sure you have for the `Custom Design` field for both products and categories set to `--Please Select--` (this means no design change.)

This is just a shot in the dark. Based on the info you provided that's the best I can do.

Comment: Smashing! You are a star. I figure that the sql template that I used to input the content has "default" in the design tab for each product. I will double check and correct. Thanks again, you made my day!